# Listen for global key press in Node.js

Tags: node.js, keypress

I am trying to listen for global key press, and I checked other stack overflow questions that is similar to mine. I used iohook, but an error came out.

```
refresh_locale_list [476]: GetKeyboardLayoutList(0, NULL) found 1 layouts.
refresh_locale_list [493]: Received 1 locales.
load_input_helper [866]: refresh_locale_list() found 1 locale(s).
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there another solution?

(I am just using it for a simple node app)

node version: v14.15.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible there is error with node v > 13.x on Windows

Try one of node versions **<= 13.x**